# Counting MySQL GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So, I have next table structure :

[image: Table data Image]

Is there a way to make SQL query that counts simillar hashes in `r_hash` column, than founds this hash in `hash` column and returns an uid, and count of hashes?

For example - uid - 21520578; type - 1; count - 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query

```
SELECT T1.uid, T1.type, T2.count 
FROM table T1,
(
  SELECT r_hash, COUNT(*) AS count  
  FROM table 
  GROUP BY r_hash
) T2 
WHERE T1.hash = T2.r_hash
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using join

```
SELECT t1.uid, t1.type, COUNT(t2.id) as `count`
FROM table AS t1
LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t2.r_hash = t1.hash
GROUP BY t1.id
```

I am not tested this query.

Edit: with left join you also receive rows with count = 0.